# 403 forbidden error in access log

Tags: python, mysql, django, nginx, server

I have configured one of my sites on `nginx` on Ubuntu. This site is developed with `django`. After configuring the site, this is opening on window but on mac/iphone I am getting an `error 403 forbidden`.

I have checked the error log on the server, which is blank. But in the access log I see the following:

```
94.101.133.115 - - [01/May/2018:12:23:10 +0530] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 33 "-" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.01"
```

Comment: syslog    "uwsgi[1592]: Forbidden (Permission denied): / \n uwsgi[1592]: [pid: 1878|app: 0|req: 1/6] 122.160.186.2 () {40 vars in 697 bytes} [Tue May  1 12:40:24 2018] GET / => generated 22 bytes in 108 msecs (HTTP/1.1 403) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
"

Comment: Resolve this issue. By installing SSL, Maybe blocking our firewall. my url is https://blizzstart.com/